# write django multiple views in single template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Here Only Random_number Function is working Correctly, but random password function is not giving even console output I want to return Generated password to the html template. Is there is any problem with the code?

Views

```
def random_number(request):
    random_num = ''
    if(request.POST.get('Submit-Number')): 
        min_number = int(request.POST.get('min_number'))
        max_number = int(request.POST.get('max_number')) 
    random_num = random.randint(min_number,max_number)
    return render(request,'random_number/random-number.html'), 
    {'random_num':random_num})

def random_password(request):
    random_pass = ''
    if(request.POST.get('Get-Password')):
        min_length = int(request.POST.get('min_length'))
        #max_length = int(request.POST.get('max_length'))
        all_char = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()'
        for eve in range(min_length):
            new_word += random.choice(all_char)
        random_pass = new_word
        print(random_pass)
    return render(request,'random_number/random-number.html', 
    {'random_pass':random_pass})
```

Templates

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">1</div>
    <h3> Generate Random Number Here </h3>
    <form class="" action="#" method="POST"> <!-- method is posting and 
      refreshing page with new Data over Random Number -->
      <input type="number" name="min_number" value="1">
      <input type="number" name="max_number" value="10">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" name="Submit-Number" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
    <!-- <h3> Random Number = {{ random_num }}</h3>  -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">2</div>
  <h3> Generate Random Password Here </h3>
  <form class="" action="#" method="POST"> <!-- method is posting and 
    refreshing page with new Data over Random Number -->
    <input type="number" name="min_length" value="8">
    <input type="number" name="max_length" value="12">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="Get-Password" value="SUBMIT">
  </form>
  <h3> Password = {{ random_pass }}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX response ?

Answer (score 0):

use the debugger in the random_password , to checkout the why the code fails. This will help you to check out, whether you are entering in the function or not .
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()